# "The way I are"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, lyrics

I always get confused when I listen to the song "The way I are" by Timbaland.

What is the point of saying "I are" instead of "I am"?
Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Song's text interpretation/criticism is off topic unless a specific source of concern, which isn't the case here, is clearly identified. However, this is not really a question about the English language at all. Vote closing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics

Comment: Related question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/29764/28567

Comment: @snailboat: The ELU one was before my time, so I'd not seen it before. Alerted now, I've closevoted that too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In your time questions about grammar gets closed? are grammar about song lyrics explicitly off-topic here?

Comment: @HaLaBi It's not grammatically correct.  If you want to know for sure why he did it, you'd have to ask the songwriter.

Comment: @ HaLaBi: As ever, this is only my opinion - I can't speak for others either here or on ELU. But yes - I think questions asking about either the grammar or the meaning of a construction where *the only cited example* is a song lyric are well and truly Off Topic. I mean, come on! Did you seriously expect to get an answer telling you this was a "grammatically correct" usage? Does it not strike you as odd that you've never come across it anywhere else?

Comment: @FumbleFingers English is not my first, not even second language. So I am asking from my point of view. It is unfair to look at the question from your point of view as a native or fluent in English. If you think the question is too silly for you that doesn't mean it is not legit. Again, just my opinion :)

Comment: Expecting song lyrics to have more than a passing resemblance to "correct" English usage is approximately equivalent to expecting comprehension of the depth of Japanese culture from reading manga.

Comment: @ HaLaBi: Your English is obviously quite good - I would say *impressive*, if it's not even your second language. So you obviously know the cited usage is definitely not "standard". I'm not saying questions that look superficially simple to native speakers are unwelcome here (that really would be silly on a *learners* site). I'm just saying that as a general rule of thumb it's not worth trying to explain/analyse any usage where the only instances anyone can easily find are either song lyrics themselves, or obvious references *to* those lyrics.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the complement about my English :) but I am seriously amazed with English, my questions was a pure inquiry because it sounded so awkward to me this (I are) thing. Anyway I respect your opinion :)

Comment: [Is You Is or Is You Ain't My Baby?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5LFD9VDq88)

Comment: HaLaBi If I may clarify: before asking this question, you were unaware that song lyrics are not always grammatical. Now that we've informed you, you've gotten the information you really needed and are know for the future, but the question itself has no real answer (other than "Song lyrics aren't always grammatical") This is similar to questions based on typos. The asker doesn't *know* it's a typo, so they ask. But once we've told them it's a typo, they don't have a question anymore. So we close. That doesn't mean we don't want you to ask other questions :) And your English is great! @Fumble

Answer (score 2):

I attribute this song title to one or more of the following: ignorance, drunkenness, or deliberate artistic license.

- Ignorance: The person who wrote the song's title might have actually believed that the construction "I are" is grammatically correct. They'd be wrong, but musicians aren't great grammarians.
- Drunkenness: The person who wrote the song's title might have been drunk at the time, and by being so impaired, used grammar that they normally wouldn't use.
- Deliberate artistic license: The person who wrote the song's title decided to be "different" and stick out in the crowd. They thought it sounded interesting. They wanted to stir up discussion about the song, *like this very question*.

Bottom line is, regardless of the reason why they chose that particular construct, it is grammatically incorrect.

The only situation where the words "I are" occur in that order in grammatically correct English is in the construct `X and I are {verb or adjective}`. For example:

- Mom and I are happy.
- Spot and I are playing fetch.

The song *might* have some intentionally omitted words in it, and this is a real stretch because I haven't listened to the song, but it could be that the artistic omission could be something like:

`The Way {Some Other Person and} I Are`

...but that's anyone's guess. You'd have to ask the artist.

Comment: Really, drunkenness?  Wouldn't he have noticed after he sobered up? :-)

Comment: I think we can discount *ignorance* and *drunkenness* on this one. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_I_Are) it was co-authored by Timbaland along with Keri Hilson, D.O.E., Danja, The Clutch, and Candice Nelson. [The Clutch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clutch) alone could have been half-a-dozen people. It's unlikely they'd all be so dumb or drunk as not to notice the "slight ungrammaticality". So we can safely say it's "artistic license" echoing *'Cause I like you just the way **you are*** in a preceding line.